# Simple Cardinal Exponentiation Example

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In general, for two sets $A$ and $B$, $|A^B|$=the number of functions from $B$ into $A$.

Can someone please show that $|\{1,2\}^{\{3,4,5\}}|=8$ by showing that there are eight functions from $\{3,4,5\}$ to $\{1,2\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(3,4,5) \to (1,1,1)$

$(3,4,5) \to (2,1,1)$

$(3,4,5) \to (1,2,1)$

$(3,4,5) \to (1,1,2)$

$(3,4,5) \to (2,2,1)$

$(3,4,5) \to (2,1,2)$

$(3,4,5) \to (1,2,2)$

$(3,4,5) \to (2,2,2)$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Kenny Lau's answer is also good... and the more general one.  Now try to imagine if you had an extra element in your domain or range, how would this affect your calculation?  Reflect on this and why the $23=8$ answer makes sense, you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

A function sends one element of the domain (that is 3, 4, and 5) to exactly one element in the co-domain. Therefore, there are two choices for each element in the domain: they can be either sent to 1 or sent to 2. Therefore, there are $2^3 = 8$ choices in total.